# Sum the largest 2 values in a 4 value?

Tags: excel

How to give the value free in excel?
my excel value

```
A2 299
A3 399
A4 499
A5 599
```

i am tried in excel formula for sale buy 2 get 2 free and my price 299, 399, 499, 599 if customer buy all products then total amount is 499=599 and free is 299=399

Comment: Is it related to programming?

Comment: Please start doing some code by yourself , then if you got stucked with some exact issue, then someone will be able to  help you. Refer this link for asking proper questions 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share what you tried till now. ANd what language it is ?

Comment: i am tried in excel formula for sale buy 2 get 2 free and my price 299, 399, 499, 599 if customer buy all products then total amount is 499=599 and free is 299=399

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an [MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example)]  (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)]  (http://sscce.org)

Comment: Will it always be 4 values or can there be fewer or more values with a slightly varying discount rule, like "buy 3 get 3 free"?

Answer (score 0):

use this format working fine

```
=SUM(LARGE(A1:A4,{1,2}))
```